# Kubernetes error syncing pod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, debugging, kubernetes, warnings

I installed *Kubernetes*, but in the creation of pod reported a mistake, I do not know where the problem is, I hope you can help me

I use *centos7*, use `yum` to install *Kubernetes*.

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# rpm -qa |grep -i kube
kubernetes-master-1.2.0-0.11.git738b760.el7.x86_64
kubernetes-client-1.2.0-0.11.git738b760.el7.x86_64

[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl run   my-nginx01 --image=192.168.10.58:5002/test111/nginx  --port=80
deployment "my-nginx01" created

[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
my-nginx01-3752101197-v34jm   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          3s

[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl describe pod my-nginx01-3752101197-v34jm

Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubobjectPath           Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------           --------    ------          -------
  22s       22s     1   {default-scheduler }                    Normal      Scheduled       Successfully assigned my-nginx01-3752101197-v34jm to 192.168.6.133
  20s       20s     1   {kubelet 192.168.6.133} spec.containers{my-nginx01} Normal      Started         Started container with docker id 3e18486078c2
  20s       20s     1   {kubelet 192.168.6.133} spec.containers{my-nginx01} Normal      Created         Created container with docker id 3e18486078c2
  21s       17s     2   {kubelet 192.168.6.133} spec.containers{my-nginx01} Normal      Pulling         pulling image "192.168.10.58:5002/test111/nginx"
  20s       16s     2   {kubelet 192.168.6.133} spec.containers{my-nginx01} Normal      Pulled          Successfully pulled image "192.168.10.58:5002/test111/nginx"
  22s       16s     3   {kubelet 192.168.6.133}                 Warning     MissingClusterDNS   kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. Falling back to DNSDefault policy.
  16s       16s     1   {kubelet 192.168.6.133} spec.containers{my-nginx01} Normal      Created         Created container with docker id 0c5c9fdd19ca
  15s       15s     1   {kubelet 192.168.6.133} spec.containers{my-nginx01} Normal      Started         Started container with docker id 0c5c9fdd19ca
  11s       11s     1   {kubelet 192.168.6.133}                 Warning     FailedSync      **Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "my-nginx01" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 10s restarting failed container=my-nginx01 pod=my-nginx01-3752101197-v34jm_default(b4f373b3-20c3-11e6-81d6-000c294bd99a)"**

  11s   11s 1   {kubelet 192.168.6.133} spec.containers{my-nginx01} Warning BackOff Back-off restarting failed docker container
```

Comment: Do the logs say anything? `kubectl logs -f my-nginx01-3752101197-v34jm`

Comment: `CrashLoopBackoff` is usually indicative of an application error, so your answer lies in the logs of that container.

Comment: > Possible duplicated with [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974003/i-got-pod-errors-crashloopbackoff-from-kubernetes/50389881#50389881]

Answer (score -1):

The issue caused by the docker container which exits as soon as the "start" process finishes. Add a command that runs forever and probably it'll work. For example, recreating docker image:

```
#Dockerfile
[...]
CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"
```