# I got Pod errors: CrashLoopBackOff from kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I was trying to run simple python file on kubenetes engine. while i got following error message "Pod errors: CrashLoopBackOff". How to fix this issue?

Comment: can you submit the output of `kubectl describe pod <pod_name> -n <namespace_name>`?

Comment: Most probably the program completes and kubernetes is trying to restart the program again and again.

Comment: Please include the output of  'kubectl describe pod' as Maruf has requested. Also, have you tried running the image in Docker before trying to run it in Kubernetes?

Comment: Yes. kubernetes has restarted the program again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue caused by the docker container which exits as soon as the "start" process finishes. Add a command that runs forever and probably it'll work.
For example, recreating docker image:

```
#Dockerfile
[...]
CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"
```

Comment: Dirty? Is the easiest way to avoid container exits. After that, for sure, you have to get into the docker and debug it to put your correct CMD or ENTRYPOINT

Comment: easy doesn't necessary meant neat. For K8s, a neat way of doing what ANU V wants is pasted below (the other answer), not by modifying the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your deployment as follows:

```
   spec:
     containers:
     - image: YOUR_IMAGE
       name: NAME
       tty: true     #add this line
```

Comment: what will this do?? @suren

Comment: Will keep the terminal running.